# Violation of OO concepts?

Tags: c#, oop, design-principles

> Create a base class with a method that uses a switch case that reference the type of the children class.

Is the below piece of code violating the OO principles, if so which one?

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass Method()
    {
        switch (this)
        {
            case DerivedClass1 s:
                return new DerivedClass1();
            case DerivedClass2 c:
                return new DerivedClass2();
            case DerivedClass3 r:
                return new DerivedClass3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that a homework question?

Comment: https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/open-closed-principle/

Comment: [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're violating the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) by not taking advantage of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). Make the base class method [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) and [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) it for each derived class:

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual BaseClass Method()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public override BaseClass Method()
    {
        return new DerivedClass1();
    }
}
```

...and so on.